# XML file stored within SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xml-parsing, sas

Does anyone know the easiest way to extract an XML file from an SQL database.

Unfortunatley, the only tools i have/am allowed at work are SAS. So, is it possible to extract the file to a different location using SAS then connect to it using the XML libname?

Answer (score 0):

I am making two assumptions with this answer.

1. The XML file you want is stored as an XML object
2. You can create an XML object in your destination location using just the text from your XML file.

You can write a query to extract the XML file (stored as an XML object) as a string.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), XmlData) AS XmlString FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas but I think the xml object may just be stored as a XML text file. Can what you suggest be utilised within SAS via SQL pass through?

Comment: Do you mean as a BLOB object? I guess I don't know what you mean by "XML text file". If you just query the field, can you read the results as text? That sounds like either a VARCHAR field (in which you already have your XML text as text) or an XML Object, in which you could use the query I provided.

Comment: I meant to paste this query in as well.

If it is a BLOB Object, you could do the following:
    SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CAST(BLOBFIELD AS BINARY)) FROM YourTable

Comment: Yes, I can query the field in SAS which shows me a XML text string. The problem is that SAS truncates it. It's as though any time i connect via SAS, it automatically becomes truncated. I think the only solution is probably to XML parse it via SQL pass-through but i've been unable to do this so far...

Comment: I think the XML file is just stored as an XML object on the SQL database

Comment: When you connect in SAS you can see 4 columns and 100+ observations. One of the columns is the XML text string and I think each row is possibly a seperate XML file that have all be concatenated together.

Comment: Forgive my slow uptake. So SAS is truncating your XML as text. From your observation yesterday about the column containing XML text, did you try concatenating like you mentioned? What do the observations look like?